# Using Selenium with PyCharm CE

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium with PyCharm CE. I have installed Selenium using pip install Selenium and I'm able to use it via the terminal however when I try to use it with PyCharm I get an import error

```
ImportError: cannot import name webdriver
```

Would anyone know why Selenium would work using the terminal but not even be able to import the module using PyCharm..?

Thanks,

Comment: The project must be using a wrong interpreter. Check your interpreter settings.

Comment: I thought this too but if I go to python interpreter settings page I have only one version of python there (2.7) and I can see the Selenium module in the packages tab....?

Comment: It also allows me to 'import selenium', but not 'from selenium import webdriver'

Comment: OK, problem solved I had named the folder selenium in PyCharm and it was getting rather confused by this.

Answer (score 15):

This can be resolved in two ways:

1. pip install selenium
2. Go to Pycharm -> Perform (Cntrl + Alt + S) -> Select Project Interpreter -> Click on (+) icon -> Search for Selenium -> Select and Install Package -> Apply -> Ok

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can press alt+enter on the library that's missing in the code (most likely it will be underscored with a squiggly red line. select "import lib" from the popup menu. Pycharm will download and set it up.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `pip <http: www.pip-installer.org="">`_ on your system, you can simply install or upgrade the Python bindings::

pip install -U selenium

Alternately, you can download the source distribution from `PyPI <http: pypi.python.org="" pypi="" selenium="">`_ (e.g. selenium-2.46.tar.gz), unarchive it, and run::

python setup.py install

Answer (score -1):

To import web driver you will have to write

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

this will solve your problem