# How to click element using java in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to click in element with a correct locator but i have problem is located here `WebDriverWait(driver, 120)` saying this error message `The constructor WebDriverWait(WebDriver, int) is undefined`

```
WebElement button = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 120)).until
(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("")));
button.click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cbeb7f9edf , in the latest version of Selenium, you should create the WebDriverWait object as below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(120));
```

Comment: What's different between `Thread.sleep` and `Duration.ofSeconds`
> smart solution needed! **Need to never miss any clicks on button**

Comment: **button is displayed and missed with Duration**

Comment: If the element is displayed before 120 seconds, e.g. in 5 seconds, then Selenium will continue executing next line of code  and not wait entire 120 seconds. 

If element is displayed after 120 seconds then your test will fail with exception. 

Thread.sleep is a hard wait and should be avoided. Duration.ofSeconds() is not a method for waiting, it is just a method for giving a timeout in the Duration type.

Earlier Selenium was accepting integer/long or Duration as the second parameter. From the latest version, it seems, that the constructor accepts Duration only.

Comment: Using WebDriverWait is the right way to wait. 

As a developer, we can assess what is maximum delay possible on a page load/element load and accordingly set the timeout duration.

e.g. on an average element is taking 5 seconds to be visible, assuming it will take more on the slowest network, we can try and keep a timeout between 7 to 10 seconds.

Keeping a timeout of 120 seconds in today's scenario is very high unless the website is really so slow.

Comment: **elements displaying depends on internet speed**

Comment: @cbeb7f9edf only way to fix the error is to use the statement I gave in my answer or you for the latest version of Selenium (4.4.0) as of today. 

You code using WebDriverWait should look like below:

`WebElement button = (new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(120))).until
            (ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("")));
            button.click();`

and 
`WebElement button1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(120)).until
            (ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("")));
            button1.click();`

Comment: You can refer this link - [Using Selenium with PyCharm CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333330/using-selenium-with-pycharm-ce)

Comment: Finally **the problem was in selenium server latest version**, code working fine now with older version specifically in `selenium server standalone 3.14.0`